# How to plot multiple columns in more than one graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe (df) that looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'PORTFOLIO': 'A A A A B B B B'.split(),
                   'DATE': '01.01.2018 01.04.2018 01.07.2018 01.10.2018 01.01.2018 01.04.2018 01.07.2018 01.10.2018'.split(),
                   'TWR': '0.902394258 0.070277784 0.550490473 0.46175313 0.238824009 0.39631305 0.174549818 0.39739729'.split(),
                   'IRR': '0.109757902 0.234597079 0.049599131 0.936973087 0.455933496 0.60647549 0.154498108 0.887030381'.split()})

df['TWR'] = df['TWR'].astype('float')
df['IRR'] = df['IRR'].astype('float')
```

In my real dataframe, I have around 10 portfolios, and I wish to present each portfolio in its own graph. My attempt has been (though only succsessful for one of the columns):

```
sns.set(style ='ticks', color_codes = True)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="PORTFOLIO", col_wrap = 4, height = 4)
g = g.map(plt.plot, 'DATE','IRR')
```

I am very happy that each portfolio has its own graph (right next to eachother), but how do I get BOTH columns IRR and TWR to appear together?

I want to see each graph look something like this:

[image]

Comment: in your question your posted data is string you have to change it to float while creating dataframe. `.split()` will also create list of string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only simple change here `g = g.map(plt.plot, 'DATE', 'IRR', 'TWR')`
use

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PORTFOLIO': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'DATE': ['01.01.2018', '01.04.2018', '01.07.2018', '01.10.2018', '01.01.2018',
                            '01.04.2018', '01.07.2018', '01.10.2018', ],
                   'IRR': [.7, .8, .9, .4, .2, .3, .4, .9],
                   'TWR': [.1, .3, .5, .7, .1, .0, .4, .9],
                   })

print(df)
sns.set(style='ticks', color_codes=True)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="PORTFOLIO", col_wrap=4, height=4)
g = g.map(plt.plot, 'DATE', 'IRR', color='#FFAA11')
g = g.map(plt.plot, 'DATE', 'TWR', color='#22AA11')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This actually puts the portfolio on x-axis (instead of date). But more importantly, it does not split the portfolios on different graphs.

Comment: you just made my day :)

Comment: would you know a quick way to seperate the two lines? Either with different coloring or maybe a lable?

Comment: its simple thing